# Understanding the 802.11 frame structure and Android probe request different?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, 802.11n, network-protocols

I have read here and on Google a lot about the 802.11 Frames
but something doesn't add up.

this is what I see when I scan using ESP12 wifi

```
Byte 00-11 : a7  10  75  50  00  00  00  00  00  00  0c  00
Byte 12-15 : 40  00  00  00
Byte 16-21 : ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  
Byte 22-27 : 2a  b9  ce  e3  71  07  
Byte 28-end: ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  70  0a  00  00  01  04  02  04  0b  16  32  08  0c  12  18  24  30  48  60  6c  03  01  0b  2d  1a  ad  01  13  ff  ff  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  7f  0a  04  00  0a  82  00  40  00  40  80  01  bf  0c  92  f9  91  33  fa  ff  0c  03  fa  ff  0c  03  dd  07  00  50  f2  08  00  24  00  ff  03  02  00  01  00  75  00
```

(I think it add 12 bytes before the message , but if I start from there I get the correct order )

when I look at the wiki 802.11 frame structure page I can see that :

Address1 is ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (bytes bytes 16-21)

Address2 in 2a:b9:ce:e3:71:07 (bytes 22-27)

the Frame control is 40 00 (bytes 12-13) , and if I understadn correct it's a "probe request"

but the order doesn't make sence
becaue 40 00 is --> 0100 0000 0000 0000

and in the Wiki it mean:

- version: 01
- type: 00
- subtype : 0000

what is wrong with my logic?

Also
can it be that there is a different between Android 8 and Android 5.1?
the request is not the same?

because when I "sniff " android 5.1 device - I can see it "on the air" while when I "sniff" - android 8 device , I don't see it

(I know the MAC of both devices I'm searching )

Thanks ,

Comment: As you have a "wireshark" tag: Try looking at the frame in Wireshark, it'll decode the frame for you, so you can see if your understanding of the frame layout is correct.

Comment: I will run it using wireshark and see , and what about the second part of the question? do you know ?

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't understand it correctly. Subtype `0000` is a `Association Request` not a `prove request` (whatever a `prove request` is, I think you actually mean `Probe Request` which would be Subtype `0100` see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11_Frame_Types)).

If the `Frame Control` is is `40 00` or `0100 0000 0000 0000` it read like this:

```
Bit 00-01: Version = 01
Bit 02-03: Type = 00 => Management
Bit 04-07: Subtype = 0000 => Association Request
Bit 08-Rest: 8 differenet Flags = 0000 0000
```

The "second part" of the question (why you can't see a frame) does not have anything to do with the first part (content of the frame). This can have multiple causes (more information is needed here), you should put it into a different question. Questions about Android (how WLAN is implemented in the different versions) are out of scope here on Superuser, you should choose the appropriate StackExchange site.

Comment: I meant "Probe Request" , so what is te sniff I read? isn't a "Probe Request" from my device?

Comment: @Afik_Android no, this frame is a Association Request

Comment: Some info for the download would be helpful so this answer can be improved, thanks!